# PostgreSQL ALTER TABLE explicit locking doesn't work as expected

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to perform ALTER TABLE on a huge table without full access locking.
According to ALTER TABLE documentation:

> An ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock is held unless **explicitly** noted

Hence I do the following:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE MyTable IN SHARE MODE;
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN size SET DATA TYPE BIGINT;
COMMIT;
```

I expect that it gives me a possibility to perform SELECT queries during the upgrade.
But in fact it doesn't. Looking at *pg_locks* during the transaction I've found that:

```
SELECT c.relname, l.mode, l.granted, l.pid
  FROM pg_locks as l JOIN pg_class as c on c.oid = l.relation 
  WHERE relname='MyTable' AND granted IS TRUE;

 relname  |        mode         | granted | pid  
----------+---------------------+---------+------
 MyTable  | ShareLock           | t       | 2277
 MyTable  | AccessExclusiveLock | t       | 2277
```

So *AccessExclusiveLock* unexpectedly was taken as well and it explains why my SELECTs are hanging until the end of the transaction

I use PostgreSQL 9.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misinterpret the *unless explicitly noted* bit.

It means that, given that there are different actions grouped under `ALTER TABLE`, for some of them it's possible that a lock weaker than `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` might be sufficient, and when it's in the case, it's explicity noted in the documentation.

For instance (from
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html ):

> SET STATISTICS acquires a SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock.

...

> Changing per-attribute options acquires a SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock.

...

> Validation acquires only a SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE lock on the table being altered. If the constraint is a foreign key then a ROW SHARE lock is also required on the table referenced by the constraint

It doesn't mean that the actions that require an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock (such as changing the type of a column) could be influenced by a previous explicit weaker lock grabbed on the table in the same transaction. They are going to need an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock no matter what.

Comment: Oh, that's what it means. Thanks for explanation.